# Replace number with corresponding letter

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format some number data. For each cell within the range I need to replace the first number only with the corresponding letter. 1 = A, 2 = B etc. and then delete the 2nd and 3rd numbers.

So for example:

```
11111 --> A11
12345 --> A45
23456 --> B56
56789 --> E89
```

Is there a simple way to do that with formatting? I only need to go up to E.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with formatting.

Comment: @S7ewie you are replacing more than just the first number in your example.  You could do this with or without VBA up to letter E, but VBA would be much easier for a larger project scope, you are talking 5 IFs and some string manipulation formula in an adjacent range, it's an ugly formula to write for every True case and looks much better in VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little VBA code to accomplish what you need:

```
s = "56789"
s = Chr(Asc(Mid(s, 1, 1)) + 16) & Mid(s, 4)
```

Comment: That will not work for `66789`. OP said: _I only need to go up to E._

Comment: I guess we need clarification on that point.  What should happen for 66789?  Should it be E89?

Comment: Yes, right, he didn't say what should happen for 6,7, .. And should 2nd and 3rd numbers always be deleted or only in case it starts with 1,2,..., 5.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Sorry, I was vague on that. 66789 should be F89. I shouldn't get numbers higher than 69999 so I only said that for simplicity. But if 6 = E and 26 = Z, that's ideal.

Storax, I only need the First number as a letter and the final 2 numbers, so 2nd and 3rd can always be deleted.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Thank you! Is it possible to format those final two numbers within this to "00" so that "1" is displayed as "01"? If that's not simple it doesn't really matter, but it helps it to match up with my formatting on other sheets.

Comment: So "11111" should be "A0101"?

Comment: Based on the OP's comment here the request is totally unclear now. So in case we have the number 26123 what should be the result? Z3 or Z23 or B23 because 2 will be converted to B and 26 to Z. And which following digits digits should be deleted?

Comment: @Storax Only the first character needs converting so it will max out in practice to "I".

Comment: OP said in the comment _But if 6 = E and 26 = Z, that's ideal_ Your code will not give correct results in case `s = "A56789"`. Result will be  `Q14222`. You always have to consider wrong input. Sooner or later this will happen.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Only the last 2, the 2nd and 3rd should still be deleted as you have done. For 11111 it will show A11 which is correct. The problem is that the copy misses any leading zeros in the final two numbers so I get 1111 (instead of 11101) which should be A01. It currently shows as A1 which is fine. But A01 will match with my other formatting.

Comment: @Storax Sorry Storax you're totally right! I completely overlooked that. As Brian said its only the first character so yes it would max out at I. The only reason I originally said E was because I won't have any number that start with anything higher than a 5 so it doesn't really matter. I was trying to keep things simple but obviously confused things in the process.

Comment: @S7ewie When I try "11101" I get "A01".  Perhaps some formatting in the spreadsheet itself?

Comment: @BrianMStafford Yes and that is correct, but the data isn't copied as 11101, it will be copied as 1111 as it ignores any leading zeros. Might be easier to format separately actually. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Storax I agree about error handling.  For simplicity, I only provided the string manipulation logic and not the entire method.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be

```
Option Explicit

Function conA_E(inp As String) As String
    Dim res As String
    Dim ch As String

    On Error GoTo EH
    ch = Left(inp, 1)

    If ch <= 6 And ch >= 1 Then
        res = Chr(Asc(Mid(inp, 1, 1)) + 16) & Mid(inp, 4)
    Else
        'res = ch & Mid(inp, 4) ' In Case 2nd and 3rd digit should always be deleted
        res = inp               ' No change if first digit is bigger than 5
    End If


    conA_E = res

    Exit Function

EH:
    conA_E = inp

End Function

Sub TestIt()
    Dim inp As String
    inp = "1214222"

    Debug.Print conA_E(inp)
End Sub
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with this and it has some error case handling, OP did expand his case to F (or 6) in comments below and acknowledged always deleting the 2nd and 3rd character, only takes one mod to open this up to 6 cases rather than 5, well done.

Comment: Sorry I only just realized you answered as well. This works great! and well done for spotting my flaw haha

Comment: You only need to change `If ch <= 5 Then` to `If ch <= 6 Then`.

Comment: @Storax Yes I see that! Thank you! :D